# How to display a loader icon, while the page is rendered in React-native?

Tags: react-native, rendering, react-navigation

I am actually rendering a Complex UI in a react-native app. I am using react-navigation. Whenever I click the option in navigation drawer for my complex UI Page, the whole app hangs for 3-5 seconds and then the page is shown. What I want is a loader screen that loads immediately when I click on the option in navigation drawer and when the complex UI is rendered the loader should disappear and the UI should be shown. The app freezes because of the rendering of the UI. Is there any way to asynchronously render the UI after displaying the loading screen?

*Edit*

Below is the complex UI that I mentioned earlier. This table is loaded when I navigate to this page.

```js
// source https://snack.expo.io/@shrey/highly-responsive-sheet
import React from "react"
import { Animated, ActivityIndicator, FlatList, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View,TouchableOpacity } from "react-native"

const NUM_COLS = 15
const NUM_ROWS_STEP = 20
const CELL_WIDTH = 100
const CELL_HEIGHT = 60

const black = "#000"
const white = "#fff"

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { backgroundColor: white, marginVertical: 40, marginBottom: 80 },
  header: { flexDirection: "row", borderTopWidth: 1, borderColor: black },
  identity: { position: "absolute", width: CELL_WIDTH },
  body: { marginLeft: CELL_WIDTH },
  cell: {
    width: CELL_WIDTH,
    height: CELL_HEIGHT,
    borderRightWidth: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: black,
  },
  column: { flexDirection: "column" },
})

class Sheet extends React.Component {
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props)

    this.headerScrollView = null
    this.scrollPosition = new Animated.Value(0)
    this.scrollEvent = Animated.event(
      [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: this.scrollPosition } } }],
      { useNativeDriver: false },
    )

    this.state = { count: NUM_ROWS_STEP, loading: false }
  }

  handleScroll = e => {
    if (this.headerScrollView) {
      let scrollX = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x
      this.headerScrollView.scrollTo({ x: scrollX, animated: false })
    }
  }

  scrollLoad = () => this.setState({ loading: false, count: this.state.count + NUM_ROWS_STEP })

  handleScrollEndReached = () => {
    if (!this.state.loading) {
      this.setState({ loading: true }, () => setTimeout(this.scrollLoad, 500))
    }
  }

  formatCell(value) {
    return (
     <TouchableOpacity onPress=()>
      <View key={value} style={styles.cell}>
        <Text>{value}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }

  formatColumn = (section) => {
    let { item } = section
    let cells = []

    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.count; i++) {
      cells.push(this.formatCell(`col-${i}-${item.key}`))
    }

    return <View style={styles.column}>{cells}</View>
  }

  formatHeader() {
    let cols = []
    for (let i = 0; i < NUM_COLS; i++) {
      cols.push(this.formatCell(`frozen-row-${i}`))
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.header}>
        {this.formatCell("frozen-row")}
        <ScrollView
          ref={ref => (this.headerScrollView = ref)}
          horizontal={true}
          scrollEnabled={false}
          scrollEventThrottle={16}
        >
          {cols}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
  }

  formatIdentityColumn() {
    let cells = []
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.count; i++) {
      cells.push(this.formatCell(`frozen-col-${i}`))
    }

    return <View style={styles.identity}>{cells}</View>
  }

  formatBody() {
    let data = []
    for (let i = 0; i < NUM_COLS; i++) {
      data.push({ key: `content-${i}`})
    }

    return (
      <View>
        {this.formatIdentityColumn()}
        <FlatList
          style={styles.body}
          horizontal={true}
          data={data}
          renderItem={this.formatColumn}
          stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
          onScroll={this.scrollEvent}
          scrollEventThrottle={16}
          extraData={this.state}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }

  formatRowForSheet = (section) => {
    let { item } = section

    return item.render
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.listener = this.scrollPosition.addListener(position => {
      this.headerScrollView.scrollTo({ x: position.value, animated: false })
    })
  }

  render () {
    let body = this.formatBody()

    let data = [{ key: "body", render: body }]

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.formatHeader()}
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={this.formatRowForSheet}
          onEndReached={this.handleScrollEndReached}
          onEndReachedThreshold={.005}
        />
        {this.state.loading && <ActivityIndicator />}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default Sheet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing actual code, I can only suggest high-level solutions:

1. Consider using `requestAnimationFrame` or `InteractionManager` to schedule expensive calculations.
2. Render the loading state first, then listen to navigation focus event to start rendering your Complex UI.
3. Remember to test in production mode, because the difference with development can be signification.

Links to the concepts I mentioned:

1. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#my-touchablex-view-isn-t-very-responsive
2. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers#interactionmanager
3. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A slight modification of the second answer worked for me. I conditionally rendered my loader first and toggled the condition to render the table in a setTimeout in componentDidMount. So this gave ample for the loader to render the loader only because the timeout callback is executed only after the main js becomes free.

Answer (score 1):

Your UI probably also loads slowly because you are using a FlatList inside a FlatList. In my experience it will only cause confussion and performance issues.

One thing you might also want to do is integrate with something like Redux, to handle a global loading state, and based on that value you show a loading spinner or the data.

Comment: Actually the data is instantly available, but I am unable to render is quite slow. So I wanted the loader to be displayed when it is rendering.